# How to fix 'error: invalid_grant Invalid authorization code' when asking for reshresh_token from Spotify API?

Tags: javascript, http-post, spotify, refresh-token, insomnia

I'm trying to receive `refresh_token` for my Ionic app, I successfully receive `access_token`.

I receive `code` (`authorization_code` or `access_token`) from endpoint `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=` in my TypeScript project, I pass it to `cURL` to test how to get `refresh_token` but the only thing which I receive its error.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic MzBhNT...ZWIyZWQ=" -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=BQAjgZOFne3p8PB4ARJkrXtq...kI4xJvhQ7SutZoJqVWILCY -d redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Fmain -X POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

Expected output:

```
{
   "access_token": "NgCXRK...MzYjw",
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "scope": ...,
   "expires_in": 3600,
   "refresh_token": "NgAagA...Um_SHo"
}
```

But received error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}
```

Answer (score 11):

So after two days of trying I found this [issue](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/267) and after checking documentation I found where I was wrong. The thing is when you want to refresh token you need to send in body of POST request to /api/token endpoint **code not access_token**. In my case I was sending access_token. To receive **code** you should send same request to https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize endpoint but with parameter `response_type=code`.

Comment: If you answered your own question correctly, you should mark this as the answer.